# Daisy chain input,output channels together in golang

Tags: go, goroutine

I have the following interface and struct

```
type PiplineStep interface {
    Do(ctx context.Context, in <-chan Message) (<-chan Message, <-chan error, error)
}

type Pipline struct {
    Steps []core.PiplineStep
}
```

Now I am trying to daisy the interfaces to create a pipeline like the following

```
    for _, step := range p.Steps {
        out, errc, err := step.Do(ctx, out)
        errcList = append(errcList, errc)

        if err != nil {
            errc <- err
            return
        }

        select {
        case outer <- msg:
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        }
    }
```

But the compiler says no is this possible?

I get the following Error 'out declared and not used' i have attempted following but it appears that all steps are receiving the same chan

```
    for _, step := range p.Steps {
        var tmpOut <-chan core.Message
        tmpOut = out
        tmpOut, errcTmp, err := step.Do(ctx, tmpOut)
        errcList = append(errcList, errcTmp)

        if err != nil {
            errc <- err
            return
        }
        select {
        case out <- msg:
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: "compiler says no" is not a suitable problem description. Please show complete, compile and runnable example code and actual compiler error.

Comment: lack of a sense of humor? I get a compile time error

Comment: A variable declared has to be used. If you are not using it, replace it with  _ .

Comment: it would be used on the next iteration of the loop

Comment: No it isn't used , learn Go variable scoping rules. A variable declared in for loop statement is scoped to that statement . := is variable declaration and affectation. Here you have 2 different out variables.

Comment: ok i understand syntax is really important but look at what I'm attempting to achieve is it possible how could i achieve this?

Comment: I'm trying to chain a few goroutines together using input and output channels so the first input channel is used by the first PiplineStep which outputs a channel which will be used for the next PiplineStep step as input

Comment: _What_ compiler error do you get? This is the missing piece to your question.

Comment: You need a more complete example. You haven't shown where you're making a single channel here, and you're saying that "all steps are receiving the same chan" -- are are you making more than one channel? What is the point of the separate error values and error channel, if the error values just get put into the error channel? Maybe this blog post will provide some inspiration: https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your channel variable outside the loop if you want to re-use it in each iteration (errors and context omitted for brevity):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var pipeline Pipeline

    pipeline.Steps = append(pipeline.Steps,
            AddBang{},
            AddBang{},
            AddBang{},
    )

    src := make(chan Message)
    pipe := src

    for _, s := range pipeline.Steps {
            pipe = s.Do(pipe)
    }

    go func() {
            src <- "msg 1"
            src <- "msg 2"
            src <- "msg 3"
    }()

    fmt.Println(<-pipe)
    fmt.Println(<-pipe)
    fmt.Println(<-pipe)
}

type Message string

type Pipeline struct {
    Steps []PipelineStep
}

type PipelineStep interface {
    Do(in chan Message) chan Message
}

type AddBang struct{}

func (AddBang) Do(in chan Message) chan Message {
    out := make(chan Message)
    go func() {
            defer close(out)
            for m := range in {
                    out <- m + "!"
            }
    }()
    return out
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ItVLUBRpNA1

Comment: Is it possible to implement this using Directional channels? so that i can enforce that the Step that created the channel is the only one able to close the channel

Comment: Or push into the channel